# How to map over an object which has a unique id for each object values and return the values to a React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am working on a redux project where I want to retrieve the values stored in API server.I want to store the data from the API in my redux store and then retrieve the values and display it in my react component.The data in the API server is in the form of an object but has a unique id for each value.So,in my case, the data is a list of posts.So, each post has a unique id and has all the other details like timestamp,post-title,post-author etc.This is how the default data from the API for posts looks like:

```
const defaultData = {
  "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": {
    id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd',
    timestamp: 1467166872634,
    title: 'Udacity is the best place to learn React',
    body: 'Everyone says so after all.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    category: 'react',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 2
  },
  "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": {
    id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez',
    timestamp: 1468479767190,
    title: 'Learn Redux in 10 minutes!',
    body: 'Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.',
    author: 'thingone',
    category: 'redux',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 0
  }
}
```

**Note:** The "id" which is a random number here(like "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd") becomes an integer, i.e the 1st post gets the  id 1 ,the 2nd gets 2.

So, I am able to store the data from posts API in my redux "Store". And I converted the posts object into an array(as we cannot map over an object) because I want to map over this array and show the data in my React component.But,I am not able to see the result of the array in my component,maybe that's because it has an id before each object in the array.This is how I am trying to map over the arrayand I do not get any error,but I do not see the results from the object in component.My component file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts())
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading : false
      });
    //  console.log(this.props.posts.posts[0])
    })
  }

  render() {
//  console.log(this.props.posts.posts)   
  const obj = this.props.posts.posts;
  let arr;
  if (obj) {
     arr = Object.values(obj); //Converting an Object into an array
  }
  console.log(arr);         //returns the converted array from an object

    return(
      <div>
              {
                arr               ?
                <div>
                { arr.map(post =>
                   {
                      <div>
                          {post.title}
                      </div>
                    })
                  }
                </div>
                                  :
                <div>
                  No Data
                </div>
              }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { posts: state.posts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

And when I console.log my state,the converted array looks like this:

[image: array-of-the-converted-object]

When expanded looks like:

[image: expanded-array]

I want to retrieve almost all of the values from the above array.Can anyone please show me how to get the data from the array and map over the array to show the values in my React component?

Comment: you'll love `console.table(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot `return` inside your map.

```
  render() {   
   const obj = this.props.posts.posts;
   let arr;
   if (obj) {
     arr = Object.values(obj); //Converting an Object into an array
   }

   return (
    <div>
      { arr ?
        <div>
          { arr.map(post => {
              return (
                <div key={post.id}>
                  {post.title}
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div> :
        <div>
          No Data
        </div>
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

or, alternatively, drop the curly braces with a oneliner:

```
arr.map(post => (<div key={post.id}>
                   {post.title}
                 </div>
                )
       )
```

and don't forget the `key` attribute. 
I also suggest you abstract way your dumb components. It'll make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your data as an object, and use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys, map over the keys, and use the keys to access nested objects. If you don't know the shape of your data source, you could use recursion.

Here is a working [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n58vw56wml) where I've taken your data source and turned it into a table to illustrate how to do so.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';


const defaultData = {
  "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": {
    id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd',
    timestamp: 1467166872634,
    title: 'Udacity is the best place to learn React',
    body: 'Everyone says so after all.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    category: 'react',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 2
  },
  "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": {
    id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez',
    timestamp: 1468479767190,
    title: 'Learn Redux in 10 minutes!',
    body: 'Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.',
    author: 'thingone',
    category: 'redux',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 0
  }
}

const TableHeader = ({ fields }) => (
  <thead>
    <tr>
    {
      fields.map( field => <th key={ field }>{ field }</th>)
    }
    </tr>
  </thead>
);

const TableBody = ({ data }) => (
  <tbody>
    {
      Object.keys(data).map(
        datum =>
          <tr>
          {
            Object.keys(data[datum]).map(
              field => <td>{data[datum][field]}</td>
            )
          }
          </tr>
      )
    }
  </tbody>
);

const App = () => (
  <table>
    <TableHeader fields={ Object.keys(defaultData[Object.keys(defaultData)[0]]) } />
    <TableBody data={defaultData} />
  </table>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.Will surely try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need map your data. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
  {props.incomingDataArray.map((singleArrayItem, index) => {
    return (
    <li key="list + index">{singleArrayItem.commentCount}</li>
    <li key="list + index">{singleArrayItem.timestamp}</li>
    )
   })
  }
  </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: don't forget to add a `key` to the returned component (which you can abstract away too)

Comment: i'm not sure your answer is helping the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the help.just let me give it a try.Will update you guys in a minute

Comment: With ReactJS you can’t have two siblings components returned. You need to wraps your two <li> inside a <ul key=“...”> or a <div key=“...”>. The key attribute need only be one time.  Best thing to do, though, is to create a dumb component.